# Select 5, 10, 15, 20 and so on with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I want to display items in a dropdownlist like 5%, 10%, 15%, 20% until 100.
Is there a way to bind an intelligent LINQ query to the datasource that will do this for me?

Comment: That's LinqToObjects, not Linq-to-entities.

Comment: "LINQ query" is like "ATM machine". (don't worry, I catch myself saying it, too.)  :-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx):

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 20).Select(x => 5 * x);
```

Or, in a more LINQ-like syntax:

```
from x in Enumerable.Range(1, 20)
select (x * 5);
```